# Matching a sequence of dot-separated digits of variable length with regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I am parsing text from an Excel spread sheet using Java.

I need to validate whether a sequence of 3 integers is present in the text.

The sequence of integers is:

- comma separated inside
- whitespace-delimited outside

Integers in the sequence can either have 1 or 2 digits.

This is my attempt:

```
*((\d|\d\d)[^\w](\d|\d\d)[^\w](\d|\d\d))*
```

With the * meaning that I can have characters before it, and the [\d|\d\d] being a number of either one or two digits, and [^\w] being a non word character?

- Valid text: `CPI WEIGHTS 05.1.2 : CARPETS & OTHER FLOOR COVERINGS`
- Invalid text: `CPIH INDEX 05.2 : HOUSEHOLD TEXTILES 2005=100`

Comment: Could you provide some literal examples of the in and out? It's not utterly clear from your question.

Comment: I have added some examples

Comment: I am not sure what is unclear. Every title that I want to keep has a number in it of the form xx.xx.xx, where xx can be one or two digits. The first one has 05.1.2, so I want to keep that, but the second one only has two numbers, not three, 05.2, so I want to discard that.

Comment: I answered the question with the info from your last comment. You should clean up your question and specify that, along with a good formatting for the examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last comment actually clarifies the question a bit.

Assuming you are looking for a dot-separated sequence of 1 or 2 digits, externally delimited by whitespace, here's an example:

```
String ok = "CPI WEIGHTS 05.1.2 : CARPETS & OTHER FLOOR COVERINGS";
String notOk = "CPIH INDEX 05.2 : HOUSEHOLD TEXTILES 2005=100";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,2}(\\.|\\s)){3}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(ok);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Found: %s%n", m.group());
}
m = p.matcher(notOk);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Found: %s%n", m.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
Found: 05.1.2
```